# Do I need to add "in" before "an English-speaking country" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis, ellipses, elision

1 All my life, I have dreamed of living somewhere overseas, potentially an English-speaking country.

2 All my life, I have dreamed of living somewhere overseas, potentially in an English-speaking country.

Are both sentences grammatically correct, and do they convey the same meaning?

I asked several native speakers about this question but kept getting conflicting answers. Some said the ''in'' was not needed, others said the ''in'' was needed for grammatical accuracy, and still others said both versions were grammatical but conveyed different meanings.

I know it is ungrammatical to say ''I have dreamed of living an English-speaking country" and the correct way to say such a thing is ''I have dreamed of living in an English-speaking country''. The reason why I think sentence 1 could be correct is that I assume the phrase ''potentially an English-speaking country can function as an appositive phrase to provide additional information about ''somewhere overseas." It is not necessary to the structure of the sentence, but it adds extra meaning to it because it explicitly states that one of the potential options I have in mind is an English-speaking country. If I removed it, there would be no way for the listener to tell what type of overseas location I am considering living in.

If sentence 1 is ungrammatical, could someone explain why, at 3:44 of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecN15c3gZYg), a person (she is a native English speaker from Australia) says: " I would definitely love to live somewhere overseas, potentially France, because I'm learning French"? If I didn't hear it wrong, she didn't use the preposition ''in'' before "France.'' Is it a slip? Or is the omission of ''in'' grammatically acceptable in that context?

Here are the answers I got from different native speakers:

(1)

Both sentences are fine and have the same meaning. I have no idea how they might have different meanings.

(2)

2 is correct and sounds right also.1 sounds wrong. It might be technically correct, depending on interpretation, but I wouldn't use that form in written English.

(3)

With “in” is better but if we were talking, I wouldn’t notice it as “wrong” either way. Technically I think it needs the “in” in there. Usually I try to make things into multiple sentences and see if it makes sense.

I have dreamed of living somewhere. I have dreamed of living in an English-speaking country.

It needs the “in” so my instinct says it’s a grammatical need.

(4)

You do not need the "in." The contrast that you are doing with "potentially," creates "elision." (syntactic elision).

This happens in simple comparatives. "You are taller than I am tall." or "you are taller than me." It's the deletion of identical items that are in phrases that contrast with one another.

(5)

In the second part of the sentence, there is an ellipsis (“omission from a clause of one or more words that are nevertheless understood in the context of the remaining elements” -*[source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))*. When you add the missing word back in, I think you can see why you need the preposition:

*All my life, I have dreamed of living somewhere overseas, potentially [living] [in?] an English-speaking country.*

When “live” means “to have your home in a particular place” ([source](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/live1?q=Live), which is what I think you mean, it is intransitive. Therefore, if you want to add additional information about the “living,” you need to add an adverb. Notice you did this in the first half of the sentence, where “somewhere overseas” modifies “living.”

When it is used transitively, it means “to spend your life in a particular way,” as in “live happily ever after” or “live your dreams.” So “live an English-speaking country” is grammatical. However, it doesn’t make a lot of sense, and it wouldn’t mean what I think you want to say.

(6)

The second version is better because of the following:

Doesn't work: I have dreamed of living somewhere overseas, potentially a luxury yacht.

Works better: I have dreamed of living somewhere overseas, potentially in a luxury yacht.

Doesn't work: I have dreamed of living an English-speaking country.

Works better: I have dreamed of living in an English-speaking country.

Doesn't work: I left my phone somewhere, possibly the bathroom.

Doesn't work: I left my phone the bathroom.

Works: I left my phone somewhere, possibly in the bathroom.

Works: I left my phone in the bathroom.

(7)

To me both sound fine but there is a bit of a difference in meaning. I'm trying to think of how to explain it, this is the best I can come up with:

"Potentially an English-speaking country" sounds a bit more like your biggest desire will be fulfilled by picking the name of an English-speaking country from a list to move to.

"Potentially in an English-speaking country" sounds like there is something relatively smaller (like a city or a type of landscape or a geographic feature) that is attracting you the most rather than the country as a whole, and this feature may or may not happen to be in an English-speaking country.

Like the first one would be like "I want to live in the UK, I don't care where, just give me a ticket to the UK and I will be happy" whereas the second one would be like "I want to live in a place where it's cool and rainy and there are big mountains and forests nearby, oh, Seattle or Vancouver would fit the bill and they happen to be in English-speaking countries!"

(8)

My native-speaker vibe (not my English teacher understanding) is that:

In the first one, "somewhere" is a country; in the second, "somewhere" is a place within an English-speaking country.

(9)

Both sentences are grammatically correct but they each communicate something slightly different.

(10)

Both sound totally fine.

To me #2 is the full "correct" version and what I would most likely use in writing.

The "in" is implicit (In English you always live *in* a country) so because of this #1 can be dropped/omit the word but my native speaker brain understands it is still there

Comment: Me (native BrE speaker) I'd drop the *potentially* and the problem disappears. Dreaming of living somewhere overseas is already about a possibility or potential happening, no need to labour the point.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The meaning is not the same after dropping "potentially". The particular hope expressed in this sentence is not "to live in an English speaking country overseas", which is restrictive, but instead  "to live overseas, and at the worst eventuality, even in a  country where Englisjh is not spoken".

Comment: @LPH - In that case, the word should be _preferably_, not _potentially_.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree, "potentially" is not idiomatic in this context. "If possible" would also be idiomatic, apparently.

Comment: But at 3:44 of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecN15c3gZYg), a person (she is a native English speaker from Australia) says: " I would definitely love to live somewhere overseas, potentially France, because I'm learning French". Do you guys think that the use of ''potentially'' is awkward in that context?

Comment: "Potentially France" means "France is a possible choice". @LPH interpreted your example sentence as meaning "I would prefer an English-speaking country", but it actually means "possibly in an English-speaking country".

Comment: @KateBunting or "perhaps", as 'potentially" doesn't imply preference. But potentially should be edited as it jars and spoils the question.

Comment: The native speaker from Australia has chosen her words badly. We all are capable of doing the same. Oh, and from her name I don't think Kate Bunting is a guy. I'd avoid that type of address.

Comment: @David - That's exactly the point I was making - that _potentially_ doesn't imply preference.

Comment: Of the following two, I would pick the first, but the second doesn’t seem incorrect: *I want to live somewhere else, maybe France. I want to live somewhere else, maybe in France.*

Comment: To your main point, I don't think it makes much difference whether you use "in".

Comment: It's fine to elaborate on *somewhere.* People already know you live *in* countries, *on* islands, etc.

Comment: The first two examples are both correct, depending on the context.

Sadly, most of the rest of the exposition is confusing, at best.